# Unable to clean ^[(B control characters from log file

Tags: linux, rhel

I am trying to clean all color control characters from log file. I am able to clean all other control characters except `^[(B` . Please help me to clean this control character also.

I am using these combination to clean control characters.

```
cat $LOGFILE | sed -e 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' > $LOGDIR/Temp.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sed` command only matches color control sequences.  `^[(B` is for setting the font/character set mapping (see [console_codes(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html)).

If the *only* control characters in your logfile are color sequences and `^[(B`, you can remove them all with

```
sed -e 's/\x1b\(\[[0-9;]*m\|(B\)//g'
```

For an expression that matches all possible control sequences, see eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33925425/4228744 (Python)

Comment: The doco of Sindre Sorhus' `ansi-regex` is spectacularly wrong.  It has the date for ECMA-48:1976 wrong by two decades.  This made me look hard at the regular expression itself.  The doco is spectacularly wrong there, too.  Far from covering *more* than all ECMA-48 control sequences, as it claims, it covers *less*.  There is quite a range of what ECMA-48 §5.4 defines that it won't correctly match.  Interestingly, the Stack Overflow answer is pointing out much the same thing about another regular expression with poor coverage.

Comment: agree - there's no point in replicating poor answers.

Comment: I've removed the reference to the misleading one.  I considered just pointing to the SO answer, but the Python syntax is sufficiently different to sed that it wasn't really helpful on its own.

Comment: You rock Naga....perfect solution..thanks for help